# Need to setup sublime for kubectl edit

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am using mac. When I try kubectl edit it opens on default vi editor but I cant save it after making any change in Vi editor. I am not new to vi editor but for kubectl edit it just doest not let me save my changes.

I want to configure kubectl edit to open in sublime text.
Please let me know how to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the question. I found it. 
all i need to add KUBE_EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/sub
in my bash_profile.

Answer (score 4):

Adding `KUBE_EDITOR=/usr/local/bin/sublime` in my bash_profile worked for me. However, the process forks and immediately cancels any changes made.

This was fixed by telling sublime to wait with -w flag.  `KUBE_EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/sublime -w"`

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods to set kube-editor

**Method-1**

Set environment variable, key as *KUBE_EDITOR* and value as editor executable file path including filename

```
KUBE_EDITOR=<EDITOR_EXEC_FILE_PATH>/<EXEC_FILE>
```

**Method-2**

Set editor on fly

```
KUBE_EDITOR="<EDITOR_EXEC_FILE_PATH>/<EXEC_FILE>" kubectl edit <RESOURCE>/<NAME>

eg: KUBE_EDITOR="/usr/bin/gedit" kubectl edit deployment/my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your bash_profile

```
export KUBE_EDITOR='open -a "Sublime Text" --wait'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, an option is just to set the EDITOR environment variable, so that it works for `kubectl`, but also other tools

```
export EDITOR='subl --wait'
```